# Supposed vs Thought

Tags: verbs

How do we suggest that one had something else in mind? with thought or supposed or something else?

Alice arrives at 8. 
Bob says to Alice: 
"I thought you'll be here at 9." or "I supposed you'll be here at 9" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side note: You can't mix tenses like that. It should be, "I thought you would be here" or "I supposed you would be here." Or "I think you will be here." The past tense "thought" with the future "you will" doesn't make sense.

But to your question: Both sentences are grammatically correct and meaningful. They have slightly different connotations. "Think" is a general word, indicating that you have an idea in your head. "Suppose" means to assume, or to accept as a tentative conclusion. In this context, "supposed" has the connotation of "I just took it for granted that this is what you would do".

For example, you might say "I thought you would be here" to mean that this is what you expected to happen, it did not happen, but you are not drawing any particular conclusion. You are not angry that the person wasn't there, etc. But "I supposed you would be here" implies that you are disappointed or upset that they weren't. Or in context, it may mean that you assumed they would be here, but you now realize that was a bad assumption on your part, and the point is not that they didn't live up to your expectations, but rather that you now realize that your expectation was based on a faulty assumption.